# Router Zyxel NBG334W reboots continuously

Tags: networking, router

Router keeps rebooting itself.

It started to happen when connected both wired and wirelessly to multiple computers.

Now nothing is plugged into it except the power adapter. The problem persists. I have tried 3 different adapters (with enough voltage and current), no difference.

The sequence is:
1) Flashing green power light.
2) Flashing green power light, solid green WAN/internet light and wired connection lights 1,2,3,4.
3) Flashing green power light, solid amber WAN/internet light and wired connection lights 1,2,3,4.
4) Steady green power light and wireless light.
5) back to number 1

The router never gets to a position where I can connect to the web configuration.

The only way I can stop it is by holding in the reset button on the router. However, that means I lose all my settings, so I can't keep doing that.

Edit:
A commenter asked 'what is the question'?  Hmmmmmmmmm, let's think....

Oh, it's probably

'How do I get the router to stop rebooting itself forever?'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Verify the problem isn't your connection.  If this I actually a cable gateway, the behavior you describe, is often seen when there is to much signal noise for the device to handle.  If that's not it then you have no choice but to replace the device.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a gateway, just a plain old router. There can't be any signal noise, because there's no cables attached other than the power cable.